# Python - Spyder gets hang while using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, spyder

Recently I am facing serious issue with combination of spyder + pandas + ipython.

I am using Spyder which is using iPython. I am trying following code which is working well:

```
import pandas as pd
x = [list(range(5)) for i in range(1000)]
pd.DataFrame(x)
```

But when I assigned same DataFrame to variable of same or different name it goes into hang phase (not coming out even after 30-45 minutes)

```
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
## OR
y = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Same code is working well when I tried it in python console or ipython console.

Following are the related packages I have installed on my system.

```
ipykernel                 4.0.3                    py27_0  
ipython                   4.0.0                    py27_0  
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython-notebook          4.0.4                    py27_0  
ipython-qtconsole         4.0.1                    py27_0  
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py27_0  
ipywidgets                4.0.2                    py27_0  
pandas                    0.16.1               np19py27_0  (Also tried 0.16.2)
python                    2.7.10                        0  
spyder                    2.3.6                    py27_0  
spyder-app                2.3.6                    py27_0
```

I am having Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Let me know if you want more information.

Thanks
Vishnu

Answer (score 2):

This [has been reported as a bug in Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2744), a fix has been prepared, and it will be available in the very next version. Right now I am using the workaround of calling it with a dummy `column` argument.